# How to extract week of the month from date PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to extract from a DATE type the *number of the week within the month* (NOT in the year).

*Example*: today's date is 07/08/2018. I do NOT want `32` as a result (week in the year) but `2`, since today is the second week of August.

I would expect something like

```
SELECT EXTRACT($func FROM current_date);
```

with result: `2`

Where the first week of the month lasts from the first day of the month until the first Sunday (which may last from 1 to 7 days for the first week, e.g. for this month the first week lasts from Wednesday 1/8/2018 to Sunday 5/8/2018, 5 days).

Adding the calendar of this month to give more context to users:

[image: August 2018]

Comment: What do you mean by *week*? Is the first week of August 2018 the date range 2018-08-01 to 2018-08-05 (first Sunday), the date range 2018-08-01 to 2018-08-07 (first seven days), or something else?

Comment: first week of August 2018 the date range 2018-08-01 to 2018-08-05

Comment: I don't think it exists as such, so you would have to calculate the week in the year of the first week in the current month and subtract that from the current week in the year, plus one week as otherwise your month week would start at zero

Comment: what should be the output for '2018-12-31', of for '2022-01-01' be ?  see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=dd2c5b27f24722bcb330360517241588)

Answer (score 3):

Another option would be to use [`TO_CHAR()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-formatting.html), like this:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR( CURRENT_DATE, 'W' )::integer
```

However this returns `1`, too, as it counts weeks FROM the 1st of the month... (Thus not from a Monday or a Sunday.)

Answer (score 3):

I've tested this & it appears to work, weeks 0 - 5:

```
SELECT CEILING(
    (DATE_PART( 'day', CURRENT_DATE ) - 
     DATE_PART( 'dow', CURRENT_DATE )
    ) / 7)  ;
```

Simply: Find the prior Sunday, divide by 7.

However for months where the first week *starts on Sunday* (a full week), an adjustment needs to be made so its ranking behavior *(0 - 5)* is the same as other months *(see flag "is_1st_week_7")*. **

Note that in raw form it calculates *(somewhat counterintuitively)* a negative value for the first week, but it'll round up (CEILING) to a zero.

***(my prior reply had this functional bug)*

at [dbfiddle.uk:](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=e70251943588251fb1883fa6fa44a2dd)
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=e70251943588251fb1883fa6fa44a2dd

```
WITH _dt (dt, i ) AS (SELECT *
FROM  ( SELECT '2023-01-01'::DATE + i AS dt , i FROM  (SELECT generate_series( 0, 365, 1 ) i ) i ( i) ) dt
) 
SELECT
*
,        ROUND((((dom) - dow) / 7)::NUMERIC, 2 )  - is_1st_week_7 AS raw_wom /** raw week of month **/
,CEILING(ROUND((((dom) - dow) / 7)::NUMERIC, 2 )) - is_1st_week_7 AS wom /** week of month **/
FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT
 -- full first weeks start the month off with 1 instead of 0, so need to decrement by 1 (above)
 (DATE_PART( 'dow'  , (dt.dt - ((DATE_PART( 'day', dt.dt )::INT)-1)))=0)::INT AS is_1st_week_7
,dt.dt                               /* the date    */
,DATE_PART( 'month', dt )    AS mo   /* month       */  
,DATE_PART( 'day'  , dt.dt ) AS dom  /* day of month*/  
,DATE_PART( 'dow'  , dt )    AS dow  /* day of week */  
,DATE_PART( 'year' , dt )    AS yr   /* year        */ 
FROM _dt dt
) dt
ORDER BY dt 
;
```

Comment: TY @Vzzarr for helping clean up the preamble... :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get the number of the week in the  month is to calculate the number of week in the year, and subtract the number of week of the first day of that month:

```
WITH dates AS (SELECT generate_series as d
               FROM generate_series('2022-06-01'::timestamp,
                                    '2022-07-31'::timestamp,
                                    '1 day'::interval))
select d.d,
       TO_CHAR(d.d, 'day')                         as day_of_week,
       DATE_PART('week', d.d) - date_part('week', date_trunc('month', d.d)) + 1
FROM dates d;
```

This works for all months except for January, in January, the week of the first day of the month is the last week of the previous year, so we need to take that into consideration:

```
WITH dates AS (SELECT generate_series as d
               FROM generate_series('2022-01-01'::timestamp,
                                    '2023-12-31'::timestamp,
                                    '1 day'::interval))
select d.d,
       TO_CHAR(d.d, 'day')                         as day_of_week,
       DATE_PART('week', d.d)                      as week_of_date,
       DATE_PART('week', date_trunc('month', d.d)) as week_of_first,
       (
           CASE
               -- in January, the week of the first days is the last week
               -- of the previous year, we need this as the week '1' of
               -- january
               WHEN extract('month' from d.d) = 1 AND DATE_PART('week', d.d) > 50 THEN 1
               -- from the second week in January, the week in the month
               -- is the same as the week in the year. Since the week 
               -- starts at 0 we need to add 1
               WHEN extract('month' from d.d) = 1 THEN DATE_PART('week', d.d) + 1
               -- for the rest of the months, this formula works 
               --   week_of_date - week_of_first_day_of_month
               ELSE DATE_PART('week', d.d) - date_part('week', date_trunc('month', d.d)) + 1
               END
           )                                       as week
FROM dates d;
```

Answer (score -2):

Your *week of the month* is business data. Usually, business data belongs in tables.

Data in tables is easier to audit than complicated date arithmetic. (Witness all the incorrect date arithmetic in the answers here.) It's simpler to implement arbitrary logic with data in tables. It's easier to understand and troubleshoot, too.

```
create table my_calendar (
  cal_date date primary key, 
  cal_year integer not null 
    check (cal_year = extract (year from cal_date)),
  cal_month integer not null 
    check (cal_month = extract (month from cal_date)),
  cal_week integer not null 
    check (cal_week between 1 and 5)
);
```

I included the year and month (cal_year and cal_month), because that's the next thing everyone seems to need.

Some starter data.

```
insert into my_calendar values
('2018-08-01',  2018, 8, 1),
('2018-08-02',  2018, 8, 1),
('2018-08-03',  2018, 8, 1),
('2018-08-04',  2018, 8, 1),
('2018-08-05',  2018, 8, 1),
('2018-08-06',  2018, 8, 2),
('2018-08-07',  2018, 8, 2),
('2018-08-08',  2018, 8, 2),
('2018-08-09',  2018, 8, 2),
('2018-08-10',  2018, 8, 2),
('2018-08-11',  2018, 8, 2),
('2018-08-12',  2018, 8, 2),
('2018-08-13',  2018, 8, 3),
('2018-08-14',  2018, 8, 3),
('2018-08-15',  2018, 8, 3);
```

And a query to verify the logic.

```
select cal_date
from my_calendar
where cal_year = 2018 
  and cal_month = 8 
  and cal_week = 1
order by cal_date;

cal_date
date
--
2018-08-01
2018-08-02
2018-08-03
2018-08-04
2018-08-05
```

Carefully control privileges in this kind of table. You probably want everybody to be able to read from it, but almost nobody should be able to write to it.